# What are best practices for deleting/altering cassandra columns of collection data-type?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1, column-family

In our Cassandra table, every time we change data-types of "collection-type" columns it start causing issue. For example:

For changing datatype from `text` to `Map<text,float>` we do this:

- drop existing column
- wait for cassandra to assimilate this change.
- add column (same name) but different data-type.

This reflects fine in all nodes, but Cassandra logs start complaining during compaction with:

> RuntimeException: 6d6...73 is not defined as a collection

I figured out the `comparator` entries are not correct in `"system.schema_columnfamilies"` table. Dropping table and recreating it fixes the problem but its not possible always.

Are there some best-practices when we are dealing with collection type columns in situations like above ?

> database-version:   DataStax-Enterprise: 4.7.1   Cassandra 2.1.8.621
>   cqlsh 5.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I guess you stumbled upon one of those WAT moments in Cassandra. Its a bad practice to name a new column as previously dropped one. Sometimes it even doesn't work.
Regarding schema (or data) migrations take a look at [our tool](https://github.com/smartcat-labs/cassandra-migration-tool-java). It can help you execute schema updates while keeping data and populating fields.